# TypedQuery getResultList returning object Array instead of specific typed. getting ClassCastException while iterating in for loop

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In a Spring, JPA, Hibernate application, while fetching a `resultList`, I'm getting a `ClassCastException` when iterating the received `List<Role>` in an enhanced loop.

While debugging, the returned value inside `List<Role> roleList` variable shows `elementData = Object[10]` instead of `elementData = Role[10]` which should be right.

```
@Repository
class RoleDAOImpl{

    public List<Role> findAllRoles() {
        TypedQuery<Role> typedQuery = en.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r", Role.class);
        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }   
}


@Service
class RoleServiceImpl{

    public List<RoleDTO> findAllRoles() {
        List<Role> roleList = roleDao.findAllRoles();

        List<RoleDTO> roleDTOList = RoleMapper.convertRoleListToRoleDTOList(roleList);

        // Code inside mapper
        for (Role role : roleList) { // ClassCastException: ...model.Role cannot be cast to ...model.Role
            System.out.println(role);
        }

        return roleDTOList;
    }
}
```

Error stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.model.Role cannot be cast to com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.model.Role
    at com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.service.RoleServiceImpl$$Lambda$376/386385529.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.service.RoleServiceImpl.findAllRoles(RoleServiceImpl.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.controller.RoleController.getAllroles(RoleController.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
..
```

I expect the returned value from `getResultList()` of `TypedQuery` to be of type `Role[]` and not `Object[]`.

Debug Screenshot.
[image: Role Debug screenshot]

[image: Added example of Employee list, which shows <code>Employee[]</code> instead of <code>Object[]</code>]
Added example of Employee list, which shows `Employee[]` instead of `Object[]`

Comment: can you add complete exception with stack trace and also can you try this code `role.forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: When debugging `roleList` variable, expand it to see all elements in the list and ensure that all of them have the `Role` type.

Comment: @Deadpool Tried ```role.forEach(System.out::println)```, same error. attached the stacktrace.

Comment: @JMSilla - Getting ```Object[]``` instead of ```Role[]``` in the List<Role> reference, but getting ```Role``` objects inside the array. Attached screenshot for reference.

Comment: As the error message (and the screenshot) shows, the list does contain instances of Role. But Hibernate seems to use a different classloader than your application code, and thus the two Role classes are considered different.

Comment: @JBNizet - How to solve this issue of different classloaders?  If we compare list of Employees(in screenshot No. 2), it shows ```Employee[]``` and not ```Object[]```.

Comment: @vinit the first screenshot shows a java.util.ArrayList. The second shows a java.util.Arrays$ArrayList. Not the same class, not the same implementation. You're looking at the private members of these classes. Read the error message: `com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.model.Role cannot be cast to com.vinit.Foodplazabootweb.model.Role`. I have no idea of how you got into this problem. If I had to guess, I'd say that you're using an app server with your classes in both the app server libraries and in the deployed application.

Comment: @JBNizet - In a Spring boot MVC application with JSPs, where changes made in jsp needed me to restart a whole application everytime, so I have added ```spring-boot-devtools``` in POM which solved that problem. Now as you suggested that there may be 2 Role classed in different class loaders, I did some trial and error and by not using ```spring-boot-devtools``` solved the issue. Even now I get ```Object[]```(screenshot 1) in list, it works fine in a ```for loop```. I don't know how it is working. Could you please explain and Thanks a ton man.

Comment: Again, what you see in the debugger is the internals of the ArrayList class. ArrayList uses an array of objects to store its elements, that's all. It's still a List<Role>, and this array of objects does contain Role objects only. That's guaranteed by the generics at compile-time.